# Focus and OverWrite

Tags: jquery, focus

I have an input field which has an entry as "Enter Age".
I want to set focus to this field and have the help contents erase with the first letter written into this field.

```
    $("#enter_age").val('Enter Age').focus();
    ???
```

The user should not be burdened with the task to erase the help field field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#enter_age").value('Enter Age').select().focus();
```

This works!